# Picture upload issue - broken thumbnail

Tags: uploads

I appreciate any advice you're willing to give me -- I maintain website content for 1 client on the side, and suddenly I'm having issues with new photo uploads that I've never had before.

I'm uploading the photos the same as I have before with FTP.

All new photos I've uploaded recently appear as broken thumbnail images on my client's office computers. At home and on different devices, the photos appear uploaded fine to me. They are running Chrome browsers that are fairly up-to-date and so am I.

Could this be related to the office LAN? What else could be going on here?

Thanks again in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that can be answered without more info. What exactly means "uploaded by FTP"? Do you upload the files and then manually insert the address into the Source Code? What happens if you / the client directly tries to access the files by typing in the URL into the Browser Address Bar?

If you can remote into a computer at your clients office, take a look at the developer console. Are there loading or Server Errors in the Network Tab?

The possibilities are endless...